# YouTube: add subtitles to other user's video

Tags: youtube, subtitles

Is there a way of creating subtitles and make a pull-request-like petition to the uploader to add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If community translations are allowed for the video, you can access them at the address

`http://www.youtube.com/timedtext_video?v=<your video id>`.

If not, there is no way to do what you are asking.

I would advice publishing a link to subtitles or to subbed reuploaded content in the comments.